# Error uploading images to Parse Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to upload an image and a text to Parse. But when I click on the "upload" button, the app crashes with a `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT` error. This is the code I am working on:
    class ViewControllerUpload: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var uploadPreviewImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var uploadMessage: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var uploadImageText: UIButton!
@IBAction func uploadIMageFromSource(sender: AnyObject) {

    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    uploadPreviewImage.image = image
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    uploadImageText.titleLabel?.text = ""
}

@IBAction func uploadButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    let imageText = uploadMessage.text

    if uploadPreviewImage.image == nil {

        print("Image not uploaded")

    }else {

        let posts = PFObject(className: "Messages")
        posts["Title"] = imageText
        posts["Name"] = PFUser.currentUser()
        posts.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({
            (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

                let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.uploadPreviewImage.image!)

                let parseImageFile = PFFile(name: "upload.png", data: imageData!)
                posts["Post"] = parseImageFile
                posts.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({
                    (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                    if error == nil {


                        print("data uploaded")


                    }else {

                        print(error)
                    }


                })


            }else {
                print(error)

            }

        })


    }




}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}   
}
```

Here is also a screenshot of the log:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error message, there is a nil key or value passed in to PFObject. 
Have you checked that the `PFUser.currentUser()` is not nil?

Try using the "NSNull" value for it or make sure it is not nil by using "guard let" or "if let".

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! :)